# Encontrar celdas adyacentes en una matriz

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy teniendo problemas con encontrar y verificar las celdas adyacentes a una determinada posición dentro de la matriz ( una celda puede tener 8 celdas adyacentes). La matriz está compuesta por una lista de cadenas. Hasta ahora he probado lo siguiente pero no pasa del `assert` numero 4:

```
def cant_adyacentes(life, f, c):

"""Calcula la cantidad de células adyacentes a la celda en la fila `f` y la
columna `c`."""

   celulas_adyacentes = 0
    for i in range(f-1,f+2):
        for j in range(c-1,c+2):
            if i == len(life) or j == len(life[i]):
                break
            if life[i][j] == "#":
                celulas_adyacentes+=1

    return celulas_adyacentes
```

Además, tiene que cumplir con los siguientes `asserts`:

```
def pruebas_cant_adyacentes():
"""Prueba el correcto funcionamiento de cant_adyacentes()."""
    assert cant_adyacentes((['.']), 0, 0) == 0
    assert cant_adyacentes((['..', '..']), 0, 0) == 0
    assert cant_adyacentes((['..', '..']), 0, 1) == 0
    assert cant_adyacentes((['##', '..']), 0, 0) == 2
    assert cant_adyacentes((['##', '..']), 0, 1) == 2
    assert cant_adyacentes((['#.', '.#']), 0, 0) == 4
    assert cant_adyacentes((['##', '##']), 0, 0) == 8
    assert cant_adyacentes((['.#.', '#.#', '.#.']), 1, 1) == 4
    assert cant_adyacentes((['.#.', '..#', '.#.']), 1, 1) == 3
```

Comment: Si no he entendido mal cada matriz es una lista de cadenas en la que cada cadena es una fila. Al parecer defines célula como `'#'` y cada elemento de una matriz tiene un máximo de 8 vecinos que puede ser `#` o `.`. Si esto es así, no termino de entender las salidas esperadas, por ejemplo ¿para `['##', '##']` de donde sale que el elemento `(0,0)` tiene 8 celulas adyacentes o 4 para `['#.', '.#']`? Algo se me escapa... :) Saludos.

Comment: Hola! Es así como comentas. Cada celda tiene 8 celdas adyacentes (arriba,abajo,derecha,izquierda,y las diagonales) y no se limita a los 'bordes' de las listas. Es decir,el "tablero" se considera "infinito": las celdas del borde izquierdo están conectadas a la izquierda con las celdas del borde derecho, y viceversa. Las celdas del borde superior están conectadas hacia arriba con las celdas del borde inferior, y viceversa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código es correcto si quieres contar los elemntos adyacentes a uno dado en una matriz finita. El problema es que tu matriz es teóricamente infinita.

No se si estas limitado a hacerlo usando ciclos `for` u cualquier otra cosa. De no ser así, es muy simple si se usa slicing de listas/cadenas y la operación módulo o resto de la división entera:

- Tenemos por ejemplo el caso de la matriz:

  ```
  #.
  .#
  ```

  Y nos piden contar las células adyacentes al elemento (0,0)
- Lo que necesitamos es reconstruir la matriz de 3x3 que resultaría de centrar la que tenemos(que en realidad es infinita) en el elemento que nos indican. En nuestro caso sería obtener la siguiente matriz:

  ```
  #.#        
  .#.
  #.#
  ```
- Para hacer esto debemos tener en cuenta un par de cosas:

  - Phyton permite el uso de índices negativos:

    ```
    >>> s='hola'
    >>> print(s[-1])
    >>> a
    ```
  - Si queremos crear una lista circular o cíclica podemos hacer uso de la aritmética modular usando el operador módulo (`%`) o resto de la división entera:

    ```
    def elemento(iterable, indice):
        return(iterable[indice%len(iterable)])

    s = 'Hola-'
    for i in range(0,20):
        print(elemento(s, i))
    ```

Podemos ver como le podemos pasar un índice todo lo grande que queramos y gracias a la aritmética modular podemos recorrer con índices 'infinitos' una lista finita. Con estas dos ideas podemos iterar de forma infinita sobre cualquier iterable en ambas direcciones.

- En realida solo necesitamos los 8 elementos periféricos de la matriz anterior y contar aquellos que son `'#'`. Para ello podemos hacer uso del metodo `count`.

Con los conceptos anteriores el código queda simplemente en:

```
def cant_adyacentes(life, f, c):
    fs = life[f-1]
    fi = life[(f+1)%len(life)]
    i=(c+1)%len(life[0])
    return (fs[c-1], fs[c], fs[i], life[f][c-1], life[f][i], fi[c-1], fi[c], fi[i]).count('#')

def pruebas_cant_adyacentes():
    assert cant_adyacentes((['.']), 0, 0) == 0
    assert cant_adyacentes((['..', '..']), 0, 0) == 0
    assert cant_adyacentes((['..', '..']), 0, 1) == 0
    assert cant_adyacentes((['##', '..']), 0, 0) == 2
    assert cant_adyacentes((['##', '..']), 0, 1) == 2
    assert cant_adyacentes((['#.', '.#']), 0, 0) == 4
    assert cant_adyacentes((['##', '##']), 0, 0) == 8
    assert cant_adyacentes((['.#.', '#.#', '.#.']), 1, 1) == 4
    assert cant_adyacentes((['.#.', '..#', '.#.']), 1, 1) == 3

pruebas_cant_adyacentes()
```

`fs` es la fila que hay por encima de la que contiene el elemento sobre el que calculamos las células adyacentes.

`fi` es la fila inferior.

`i` es el índice usando aritmética modular que debemos usar para obtener los elementos de la columna situada a la derecha de la que contiene nuestro elemento diana.

Los elementos situados a la izquierda o la fila superior no dan problemas porque el propio Python entiende los indices negativos y como mucho vamos a necesitar el índice -1. Los elementos de la derecha o filas de abajo si dan problemas ya que si el indice es mayor a la longitud del iterable menos uno nos generará un error. En este último caso hacemos uso de la aritmética modular.